# Intellij "Convert to Kotlin" chokes on large file

Tags: java, kotlin, intellij-idea

It seems like Intellij's `Convert Java File to Kotlin File` function is not foolproof. When I try to run it on a very large Java code file (more than 30k lines of code), it stops half-way in the conversion process and fails silently without giving any error message.

Are there any tricks I can use to mitigate this issue and successfully convert my file? Thanks!

Comment: Report it as a bug in their tracker.

Comment: Is it possible to refactor Java file into smaller files beforehand? Then you should be able to convert each of them to Kotlin without issues

Comment: Yes, please report to http://kotl.in/issue with IDE logs attached: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085-Locating-IDE-log-files. If possible, please include the project to reproduce the bug. As a workaround, try splitting the file into smaller files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I confirm my problem is fixed in the latest Kotlin version.

Comment: Latest Kotlin compiler or latest Kotlin IDEA plugin?